# Replacing active class using JavaScript not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you select another link, it does not remove the active class. It also doesn't add the active class to the 'clicked' link.[image: This is how it shows while selecting]

Home is the default class and the third one is clicked.

I tried without the ";" at the end of the script but still shows the same.

Here's my code:

```js
let navItem = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
navItem.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let activeClass = document.querySelector('.active');
    activeClass.className = activeClass.className.replace(".active", "");
    item.className = "active";
  });
});
```

```css
.navItems {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navItem {
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar .active {
  color: #e54136;
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="navItems">
    <li><a href="#home" class="navItem active">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services" class="navItem">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects" class="navItem">PROJECTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ourTeam" class="navItem">OUR TEAM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="navItem">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of problems with your code:

- in the CSS, you didn't create the correct selectors
- in the JavaScript you weren't modifying the correct elements

```js
let navItem = document.querySelectorAll('ul li a');

navItem.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active')
    item.classList.add('active')
  });
});
```

```css
.navItems {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navItem {
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navItem.active {
  color: #e54136;
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="navItems">
    <li><a href="#home" class="navItem active">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services" class="navItem">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects" class="navItem">PROJECTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ourTeam" class="navItem">OUR TEAM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="navItem">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `replace()` method with the current setup then these are the issues to be resolved from the code and it will work fine.

**UPDATE:** The problems with the code are:

1. You are not selecting the `<a>` tag when you have class `navItem` on `<a>` and then you are controlled the `active` class also on the `<a>` tag.

   let navItem = document.querySelectorAll('ul li a');
2. Second problem is in CSS. You have used.

   ```
   .navbar .active { /* which means when child of navbar is active */
   color: #e54136;
   background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
   ```

   }

It should be:

```
.navItem.active {
   color: #e54136;
   background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
 }
```

3. Third problem is you have used `replace()` method to replace a className of `.active` which should actually be `active` only.

   ```
    activeClass.className.replace(" active", ""); // **NOTE:** There has to be a space at the start
   ```
4. Lastly you have to use `+=` to update the new class active for new item to keep `navItem` class and also add `active` class on the clicked item.

**MODIFIED CODE:**

```js
let navItems = document.querySelectorAll('ul li a');
navItems.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let activeItem = document.querySelector('.active');
    console.log(activeItem.textContent)
    activeItem.className = activeItem.className.replace(" active", " ");
    item.className += " active";
  });
});
```

```css
.navItems {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navItem {
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navItem.active {
  color: #e54136;
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="navItems">
    <li><a href="#home" class="navItem active">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services" class="navItem">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects" class="navItem">PROJECTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ourTeam" class="navItem">OUR TEAM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="navItem">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```